# export image fails using cmaple.exe but OK using maple.exe

Tags: maple

Is there a difference from running the same exact Maple commands to export a plot, when run from GUI interface, using worksheet, vs. from plain text .mpl file using command line Maple?

The following code runs OK from the GUI worksheet, but gives error

`Error, invalid FONT specification` when run from cmaple.exe.

This is on windows 10.

```
#file T1.mpl

currentdir("C:/TMP");  #or any other folder of your choice
plotsetup(default);  #start from default

  #the following commnad below export a plot to a file

plotsetup(ps, plotoutput="t.ps",  
        plotoptions=`color,noborder,portrait,height=250`);

p0:=DEtools:-DEplot( diff(y(x),x)=x, y(x), x=-2..2, y=-2..2, 
             'color' = "#00aaff",
             'arrows'='medium',
             'labels'=["",""],
             'thickness'=1
             ):

#this will send the plot to a file. 

print(plots:-display([p0],'view'=[-2..2.4,-2..2.5], 
       axis=[tickmarks=['color'='red']],
       font=["Times",bold,8]
      )
  );

#ERROR SHOWS HERE

  plotsetup(default); #rest back to default
```

The print command above, does not actually display anything, even on the GUI, since it was redirected to go to a file.

The above code works with no problem in the GUI interface, and the plots is exported OK to `t.ps` file.

I am trying to run the large Maple code I have from .mpl using command line Maple, hoping it will be faster than in worksheet, but the above problem is making it not possible.

First time trying `cmaple.exe`

Command I used is

```
"C:\Program Files\Maple 2018\bin.X86_64_WINDOWS\cmaple.exe" T1.mpl
```

May be I need an option to add to the command above?

This is using Maple 2018.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plot export driver in the Commandline Interface (CLI, aka TTY) does not know about the more modern calling sequences allowed for the various font related plotting options.

In modern Maple the font options can be specified using strings instead of names. That helps users avoid issues with assigning to alternative all-caps name forms, not all of which are protected names.

Unfortunately, it seems as if the CLI plot export driver does not know about the newer string forms. I will submit a bug report.

But you can still use the older, all-caps, name form.

Replace,

```
font=["Times",bold,8]
```

by,

```
font=[TIMES,BOLD,8]
```

Answer (score 1):

Back when I was quite current with Maple, the answer to this question would have been: the GUI and the TTY version use different plot drivers. And the TTY plot drivers are not as well maintained as the ones for the GUI, and so more recent features do not always work for them.

I am guessing that this is still the case, and that the TTY plot driver doesn't know about fonts.